# What are the basic reasons for normogonadotropic hypogonadism?

Tags: medications, blood-tests, testosterone, testicles

I'm can't fine the full known scope of reasons of male normogonadotropic hypogonadism.
From [this article](https://fpnotebook.com/endo/sex/NrmgndtrpcHypgndsm.htm) I see the two basic reasons:

- Gonadal dysgenesis variants (residually functioning ovarian tissue)
- Hyperprolactinemia
  Also there obesity can be the reason.

But are there any other reasons? For example, what if the patient is young, thin with normal prolactin and with testicles responding to [hCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_chorionic_gonadotropin) therapy?

Comment: The link you cite listed four causes.

Comment: @CareyGregory The link was added - "this article"